# Validating sitemap with Yahoo Explorer

Tags: sitemap, yahoo

I have a sitemap index on my website, which I successfully validated with "Google webmasters tools".
The declarations at the top are:

```
   <sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd"
         xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

This index lists 2 sitemaps . One of them contains "images" tags after using the `http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1` schema declaration.

When submitting this sitemap index to Yahoo explorer, I get error:

```
ERROR: FF_30000 “Not an accepted feed format file. Please consult the documentaiton for supported file formats.”
```

Any ideas?

Joel

Comment: could you specify the URL of this sitemap index, please? Just from the root tag of the file is hard to say what's wrong with it. It's very likely that not the image sitemap reference is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if Yahoo and Bing do not yet support image sitemaps, which is why they are not validating in Yahoo's Site Explorer.

To avoid getting the validation error, you could place all of your image sitemaps in a second sitemap index, and only submit that to Google through it's Webmaster Tools. This should prevent you from receiving errors from any of the other search engines, and would still allow Google to utilize that sitemap for it's image search.